# GetRegionScans method in c#

Tags: c#, graphics

I'm new to .net programming. While using the Region class in my code, I came across the following code:

```
RectangleF[] rctf=rgn.GetRegionScans(new Matrix());
```

My question is, say the region is a rectangle then what this method will return? (Points at the four corners of rectangle?). I don't think this will return the co-ordinates of a region because if it returns the co-ordinates why it should return them as an array of RectangleF object. Can anyone explain what this method does?

I got no idea about the rectangles returned by this method, all I know is they represent the region of the rectangle but not what's happening exactly when I use this method.

Edit:

If I draw a rectangle, it returns only one RectangleF object, but if I use it on a polygon with three points (Say (10,20), (25,35) and (46,78)) it returns about 45 RectangleF objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A region can be quite complex, the Region(GraphicsPath) constructor for example lets you create a region from an arbitrary complex path with curves.  Which is dealt with internally by decomposing the path into a set of rectangles that cover the path.

Which is also what you see happening when you use the polygon.  Take a piece of graph paper and draw an arbitrary triangle.  Draw rectangles on paper to cover the triangle completely, you'll see that you'll need a bunch of them, particularly to deal with triangle edges that are not perfectly horizontal or vertical.  You keep adding single pixels at the edge.

So sure, if you created the region from the Region(Rectangle) constructor then you'll just get an array back with a single element.  But that quickly explodes when the region is complex.  Notable as well is that the method deals rather poorly with very complex shapes, the internal algorithm uses recursion to calculate the rectangle set.  Which can trigger the exception that gave this web site its name.